# What name should I use for the "root" of a cycle?

Tags: data-structures, terminology, cycle, nomenclature

So, I'm writing a [cyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_order) data structure. (In C#, but my question is language-nonspecific.) It's pretty simple: just a doubly-linked list that loops around on itself.

But while all nodes are equal, I need to single out *one* of them as my default entry point and reference: what is the proper name for this?

My issue is that most terms used to single out nodes in a structure like "root", "head", "top", "primary", etc. imply a *hierarchy*, which I explicitly *do not* have or desire. Others such as "current" and "active" are more egalitarian, but imply *transience* instead.

Right now I'm considering "origin", "handle", and even just "entry".

Comment: 'head' is the usual term, and doesn't imply a hierarchy, just firstness.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Doesn't *firstness* imply hierarchy? It implies that it comes before all and after none. In a cycle, all nodes come before *and* after all nodes, including themselves. Although I could see it working as a conceptual ouroboros of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

You used **entry**, what's wrong with that?

You might use **handle** as it gives you a handle to your data.

Comment: "Entry" could be interpreted as synonymous with "value", instead of as synonymous with "ingress".

Comment: What was used and why?